# Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_enqueue_media()

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

I uploaded a theme but the theme options sea to flag an enqueued error on line 11
Help sort please

```
/**
 * AccessPress Lite Theme Options
 *
 * @package AccesspressLite
 */

if ( is_admin() ) : // Load only if we are viewing an admin page

function accesspress_lite_admin_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_media();
    wp_enqueue_script( 'accesspresslite_custom_js', get_template_directory_uri().'/inc/admin-panel/js/custom.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'of-media-uploader', get_template_directory_uri().'/inc/admin-panel/js/media-uploader.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'accesspresslite_admin_style',get_template_directory_url().'/inc/admin-panel/css/admin.css', '1.0', 'screen' );
}
add_action('admin_print_styles-appearance_page_theme_options', 'accesspress_lite_admin_scripts');
```

Comment: What version of WordPress are you using? [wp_enqueue_media()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_media) requires version 3.5.0 or later.

Answer (score 1):

As goto10 mentioned in comment, you must be using WordPress 3.5.0 or newer (when this function was added), AND your theme is calling [wp_enqueue_media](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_media) incorrectly.

WordPress codex for [wp_enqueue_media](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_media) specifically states :

> "This function should be called from the 'admin_enqueue_scripts'
>   action hook, or later."

Your theme is calling it incorrectly in `admin_print_styles` which is executed before `admin_enqueue_scripts`, meaning that the `media.php` file has not been loaded yet.

You should contact that theme developer as that is not the correct way to call [wp_enqueue_media](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_media)

If for some reason you want to call this function, or other functions in the media (or images.php) files (like when using AJAX), you will need to include the file once:

```
include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );
```